# Localhost addresses stopped working after installing Docker

Tags: windows, docker, vagrant, hosts-file

I am used to develop with [Vagrant](https://www.vagrantup.com/).

My Windows hosts file uses multiple addresses mapping which used to work just perfect:

```
127.0.0.1   whatever.local
```

But after installing [Docker Desktop](https://www.docker.com/products/docker-desktop), they have stopped working. Now my hosts file looks like:

```
127.0.0.1   whatever.local

# Added by Docker Desktop
192.168.0.13    host.docker.internal
192.168.0.13    gateway.docker.internal
# To allow the same kube context to work on the host and the container:
127.0.0.1   kubernetes.docker.internal
# End of section
```

The thing is that I also disabled Docker auto start up with windows. And even with Docker **not being active**, my previous local sites are not working when running Vagrant.

The biggest issue for me is not knowing how to debug this. I tried using `ipconfig /flushdns` but it didn't fix the problem.

Any help in the direction of finding out what is going on will be hyper appreciated :)

**Running netstat -ab returns**:

```
 Proto  Local Address          Foreign Address        State
  TCP    0.0.0.0:135            LAPTOP-793T1EMN:0      LISTENING
  RpcSs
 [svchost.exe]
  TCP    0.0.0.0:445            LAPTOP-793T1EMN:0      LISTENING
 Can not obtain ownership information
  TCP    0.0.0.0:2201           LAPTOP-793T1EMN:0      LISTENING
 [VBoxHeadless.exe]
  TCP    0.0.0.0:5040           LAPTOP-793T1EMN:0      LISTENING
  CDPSvc
 [svchost.exe]
  TCP    0.0.0.0:5050           LAPTOP-793T1EMN:0      LISTENING
 [VBoxHeadless.exe]
  TCP    0.0.0.0:7680           LAPTOP-793T1EMN:0      LISTENING
 Can not obtain ownership information
  TCP    0.0.0.0:33061          LAPTOP-793T1EMN:0      LISTENING
 [VBoxHeadless.exe]
  TCP    0.0.0.0:49664          LAPTOP-793T1EMN:0      LISTENING
 [lsass.exe]
  TCP    0.0.0.0:49665          LAPTOP-793T1EMN:0      LISTENING
 Can not obtain ownership information
  TCP    0.0.0.0:49666          LAPTOP-793T1EMN:0      LISTENING
  Schedule
 [svchost.exe]
  TCP    0.0.0.0:49667          LAPTOP-793T1EMN:0      LISTENING
  EventLog
 [svchost.exe]
  TCP    0.0.0.0:49668          LAPTOP-793T1EMN:0      LISTENING
 [spoolsv.exe]
  TCP    0.0.0.0:49670          LAPTOP-793T1EMN:0      LISTENING
 [AsusLinkNear.exe]
  TCP    0.0.0.0:49671          LAPTOP-793T1EMN:0      LISTENING
 [AsusLinkNear.exe]
  TCP    0.0.0.0:49675          LAPTOP-793T1EMN:0      LISTENING
 Can not obtain ownership information
  TCP    10.72.72.1:139         LAPTOP-793T1EMN:0      LISTENING
 Can not obtain ownership information
  TCP    192.168.0.13:139       LAPTOP-793T1EMN:0      LISTENING
 Can not obtain ownership information
  TCP    192.168.0.13:49413     20.54.37.64:https      ESTABLISHED
  WpnService
 [svchost.exe]
  TCP    192.168.0.13:61717     104.18.29.120:https    ESTABLISHED
```

Comment: Are you able to access the services via IP? 127.0.0.1 of course

Comment: @mashuptwice - Thanks for helping. No, I get `127.0.0.1 refused to connect.`

Comment: Interesting, can you confirm the services are running with `netstat` ?

Comment: @mashuptwice - When running that command it shows no connection at all, and after a while it shows:
`TCP    192.168.0.13:61696     stackoverflow:https    ESTABLISHED`  

`TCP    192.168.0.13:49413     20.54.37.64:https      ESTABLISHED`  

`TCP    192.168.0.13:61700     1:https                ESTABLISHED`

Comment: should be `netstat -ab` instead

Comment: @mashuptwice - Thanks. I updated the question and pasted the result at the bottom

Comment: I had the same problem after installing Docker - could not access local sites during frontend development. I resolved this problem by disabling network adapter 'vEthernet (WSL)', which was created after WSL enabling, during Docker installing.

Comment: @Sam - Ouh... a long time since I asked this. I ended up solving all my WSL2 problems by just not using it... I now use Linux on its own laptop and all my problems in life are gone.

Answer (score 2):

First try to clear dns cache: `ipconfig /flushdns`. Restart system.

If this does not work try this:

This could be because the docker adds an entry

```
127.0.0.1   kubernetes.docker.internal
```

in hosts file. By default the windows handles the localhost name resolution in DNS ("localhost name resolution is handled within DNS itself.") and hence the entries

```
  127.0.0.1    localhost
  ::1          localhost
```

are by default commented out.

Just uncomment or add these entries in hosts file, restart the windows system and then the localhosts address should work. This is a workaround.